# if else statement: check if a path stored in a variable exists

Tags: scripting, variable, path

I have problems with an if statement in my script. I have stored a path in a variable and want to use the if...else statement to check if the file (file1) in the path of the variable exists or not. 
This is my code:

```
variable=$/home/username/file1

if [ -f "${variable}" ]
then
    echo "$variable exists"
    exit
else
    echo "file not found"
    exit
fi
```

I have also tried `[ -f "$variable" ]` but in all cases, both statements are executed. I receive as output:

```
/home/username/file1 exists
file not found
```

I guess the main problem is, that the command itself is not working. But why does it not quit after the first exit command? Where is the big bug that I do not see?

Comment: Run the script with debugging on and you'll see what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: Which shell are you using?

Comment: How are you running the script? There is no way that the script shown here can produce both outputs. It should say `file not found` if the pathname `$/home/username/file1` is not a regular file.

Comment: I have found the problem. The path was stored in a file and copied from it with the grep command. However, there was a duplicate of the path in the file which messed it up. Now I have removed the duplicate and - magically - the if statement works now.

Comment: That in itself doesn't explain how you'd manage to get a shell to run both branches of an `if`. But if the code you used wasn't exactly the one you posted, then...

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your script is in the first line.

To assign a path to a variable, simply consider it as a string:

```
variable="/home/username/file1"
```

or even this:

```
variable=/home/username/file1
```

then it works.

---

The $ sign is needed to assgn the output of a command to a variable:

```
OUTPUT="$(ls -1)"
```

Comment: This does not describe the cause of the issue nor the resolution to it.  `variable=$/home/username/file1` is a perfectly fine variable assignment and unrelated to the double output, and to command substitutions.

Comment: Thanks for the info Kevin, I guess that was a typo. I actually got the variable out of a grep command ;) but I shortened my version here for clarity

Comment: You're right. This doesn't explain the double output. But assigning the variable like in the question doesn't work for me in bash. Also, the used shell is not specified.